# C++, Add g_signal_connect event correcty to a button

Tags: c++, gtk

I created a window using gtk.then I want to add click events to the button.I tried several way but not succeeded

```
#if GTK_CHECK_VERSION(3,0,0)
    GtkBuilder* builder = newDialogBuilder("smartart.ui");
#else
    GtkBuilder* builder = newDialogBuilder("smartart-2.ui");
#endif
window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "smartartDlg"));
spin = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "summarySpin"));
m_btOk=GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "btOk"));
m_btClose=GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "btClose"));
```

Then I tried to add a signal using below code

```
 g_signal_connect (GTK_DIALOG (m_btClose), "response",G_CALLBACK(Smartart__onCloseClicked),NUll);
```

Then It Compile but gave runtime error

my Smartart__onCloseClicked method is below

```
void
Smartart__onCloseClicked (GtkButton * /*button*/,gpointer   data)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Close button clicked");
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: try g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (m_btClose), "clicked",G_CALLBACK(Smartart__onCloseClicked),NULL);

Comment: Lauch it from a terminal

Comment: How do you compile the application?

Comment: This is a part of an abiword plugin currently I am developing.I Compiled it using Terminal

Comment: @Jichao Your code worked for me.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right event for a GtkButton click should be `clicked`.

`g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (m_btClose), "clicked",G_CALLBACK(Smartart__onCloseClicked),NULL);`

refer: [GtkButton reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkButton.html)